# Can an object be assigned to multiple *categories*?

Tags: meaning

I am thinking about the very generic word *category* and was wondering:

Does the definition of the word *category* relate more to kind of a box (an item may only be in one and only one box at a time) or more to some kind of a tag (an object may have multiple tags)?

Comment: Think of _[guitar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitar)_: two major categories are **electric** & **acoustic**; two others are **classical** (nylon strings) & **steel string**; two others are **6-string** & **12-string**; etc.

Comment: You're asking about the difference between **disjoint** categories and all categories. There's a whole branch of topology devoted to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A category is a group based on shared characteristics among and between the items included therein. Any object may be placed into any number of categories. For example, a black Labrador retriever is in these categories: dogs, black dogs, Labradors, retrievers, canines, mammals, animals, things with fur, things with four legs, etc.